# Some apps appear twice in Ubuntu

Tags: audacity, desktop-apps

I'm using Ubuntu 22.10. Audacity program appears installed twice in software center, one by Muse group and the other by Dani Llewellyn (much greater in size):
[image]
I also have webcamoid installed, but it appears twice here, both are webcamoid 9.0.0:
[image]
What is the cause of this? How can i solve it?

Comment: You can do `sudo snap remove webcamoid audacity`. Or it could be something related to the `.desktop` files (Two of the same desktop file to be exact). This can be fixed by removing the duplicate desktop file present in `usr/share/applications` or `.local/share/applications`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have both snap and apt version installed, or different versions of the same software.
Try them both, if they work fine, just uninstall one of them trough
ubuntusoftware > installed > "name of the app" > uninstall.

Comment: The different sizes of each (20 MB vs 261 MB) are a great way to tell which package you are looking at.

Comment: snap is larger than apt.